# Calculations with variables in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I have been going through the Stylus docs and looking at examples, but I can't seem to get a simple calculation to work when using a variable. For example:

Works

```
margin-right: (1200 / 2)px;
```

Doesn't work

```
$siteWidth = 1200;
margin-right: ($siteWidth / 2)px;
```

I've seen many examples about using variables inside `calc` and using % before the variable name, or `{..}` around the variable, but I've tried both and neither works. Am I missing something obvious here?

### Update

I failed to mention that I am storing my variables in a separate stylus file. If I create the variable in the same file as I am using it within the calculation, it works fine, however if I try to call the variable when it is imported from another file, it doesn't work. The variables file is the FIRST thing that is included in my main `styles.styl` file, and I can use the variables site wide without issue - just not when using it in a division calculation for some reason.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/GxeGdG)**

Comment: you are using diferent variables `$siteWidth` and `$site-width`. Works fine with te correct one: http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=h1%0A%20%20%24siteWidth%20%3D%201200%3B%0A%20%20margin-right%3A%20(%24siteWidth%20%2F%202)px%3B

Comment: @blonfu That was another typo on my part when typing the question which I have now corrected, but please see the codepen example for a better recreation of the issue

Comment: @blonfu Also, please see the update which mentions that the variable is created in a separate file. I can't exactly replicate that online, but I was attempting in my codepen to recreate the error as best as I could. The example you linked to only works if the variable is created in the same file as it is used (or at least that is what my tests have shown)

Comment: In codepen you are using SASS interpolation: `#{$variable}`. Interpolation in Stylus is `{variable}` but you don't need in this case, change the last line to this: `margin-right: ($sitewidth / 2)px;`

Comment: @blonfu Please refer to my second comment. I am unable to get your syntax to work when the variable and usage are in separate files.

Comment: works fine for me in separate files too: https://codepen.io/blonfu/project/editor/DnBEjx#

Comment: @blonfu Very strange! As soon as I try exactly what you have done in my project, I receive `cannot perform $sitewidth / 2`. I also didn't know you could do that in Codepen (have an HTML structure), so I will attempt to recreate a simplified version of my project in it later and see if I get the same result. I provided an answer which actually solves my problem for now, but it isn't ideal.

Comment: @blonfu See https://codepen.io/wickywills/project/editor/XEjdpJ. Added a third styl file to your example to closer recreate my setup, and I receive the same error as in my local project.

Comment: sorry but I can't reproduce your error, works for me your last project too

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Try this instead of parenthesis:

```
#{$site-width / 2}px;
```

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Comment: Apologies, I had an error in my question (copy/pasted wrong thing from my project!) and I was meant to provide an example using the division operator. Minus works fine, but divide `/` does not. Don't suppose you know why? Question updated. Note that I've tried all variations of having `px` in and not in the variable, as well as after the parenthesis.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you have your variable defined? With or without px? Add it to the question, please.

Comment: Updated the question with a bit more info that might shed some light.

Comment: Sorry but that syntax just throws the error `expected "indent", got ";"`. I'm going to try and create a codepen example, as I'm really confused here.

Comment: Updated question with codepen that more or less recreates what I am trying to do (but with the variable in a different file)

Comment: Sorry, cannot help. I don't know why it produces that error :S it works here: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: No problem, thanks for the effort. I actually managed to solve it, though I would much prefer if the way I was originally trying, like your method, actually worked, as that is a much more usable syntax. Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit of a tricky one, but I solved my problem using the below:

```
margin-right: 'calc(-%s / 2)' % $sitewidth;
```

I have actually changed my code a bit to include a new variable to get half the width of the site, as I might use it again:

```
$halfsitewidth = $sitewidth / 2;
margin-right: '-%s' % $halfsitewidth;
```